# How to know how long my computer has not been used via GUI?

Tags: scripts, gui, input-devices, idle

How can I see for how long there hasn't been any input via mouse or keyboard on my computer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### How to see idle time; the time your computer has no input from mouse or keyboard

- To see idle time, you'll need [xprintidle](https://manned.org/xprintidle/9a24a2e0):

  ```
  sudo apt-get install xprintidle
  ```
- To show what `xprintidle` does, run:

  ```
  sleep 5 && xprintidle
  ```

  [image]

  ...which shows idle time in *milliseconds*
- If you continuously want to show the idle time in terminal:

  ```
  while true; do xprintidle && sleep 1; done
  ```

  [image]

Off course, `xprintidle` can be used in scripts to offer a more elegant way to keep an eye on idle time, but this is basically it.

#### Just for fun

...Since we do everything with an indicator these days, an example how to show idle time in the GUI, using `xprintidle`:

[image]

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import signal
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
gi.require_version('AppIndicator3', '0.1')
from gi.repository import Gtk, AppIndicator3, GObject
import time
from threading import Thread
import os
import subprocess

currpath = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

class Indicator():
    def __init__(self):
        self.app = 'show_idlet'
        iconpath = os.path.join(currpath, "idle.png")
        self.indicator = AppIndicator3.Indicator.new(
            self.app, iconpath,
            AppIndicator3.IndicatorCategory.OTHER)
        self.indicator.set_status(AppIndicator3.IndicatorStatus.ACTIVE)       
        self.indicator.set_menu(self.set_menu())
        self.timer = Thread(target=self.check_recent)
        self.timer.setDaemon(True)
        self.timer.start()

    def set_menu(self):
        # quit
        menu = Gtk.Menu()
        item_quit = Gtk.MenuItem('Quit')
        item_quit.connect('activate', self.stop)
        menu.append(item_quit)
        menu.show_all()
        return menu

    def showtime(self, section):
        return (2-len(str(section)))*"0"+str(section)

    def convert_time(self, time):
        hrs = self.showtime(str(int(time/3600)))
        mins = self.showtime(str(int((time%3600)/60)))
        secs = self.showtime(str(time%60))
        return hrs+":"+mins+":"+secs

    def check_recent(self):
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
            idle = round(int(subprocess.check_output(
                ["xprintidle"]).decode("utf-8").strip())/1000)
            GObject.idle_add(
                self.indicator.set_label,
                self.convert_time(idle), self.app,
                priority=GObject.PRIORITY_DEFAULT
                )

    def stop(self, source):
        Gtk.main_quit()

Indicator()
GObject.threads_init()
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_DFL)
Gtk.main()
```

#### How to use

1. Install `xprintidle`

   ```
   sudo apt-get install xprintidle
   ```
2. Copy the script above into an empty file, save it as `show_idle.py`
3. Copy the icon below (right-click > save as), save it as (exactly named): `idle.png`, ***in one and the same directory as the script***

   [image]
4. Run the indicator from a terminal:

   ```
   python3 /path/to/show_idle.py
   ```
5. If you want, you can add it to startup applications: choose Dash > Startup Applications > Add. Add the command:

   ```
   /bin/bash -c "sleep 10 && python3 /path/to/show_idle.py"
   ```